# C++ - detect out-of-range access

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, profiling

I would like to analyse my C++ code to find bad access in vectors and arrays (out of range access), is there a tool for that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Most c++ implementations come with a checked standard library implementation, have you checked the documentation of yours?

Comment: Well written code is the start -- add assertions liberally. At runtime, you can use `valgrind` to check for invalid memory access.

Comment: You can "assert" your code. For vector you can replace [] with at() that will throw an exception instead of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can compile with _GLIBCXX_DEBUG and _GLIBXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC defined if your are using gcc. This will enable glibc assertions to be raised if out of bounds access is requested.

Testing with valgrind::memcheck will also reveal bad memory reads

Comment: Those flags are pretty useful but I've recently found a case where they produce **segfaults**. If you try to use them along with the **boost regex** library your program will fail. I can't imagine why this happens or what else is affected. See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5911 for details

Comment: @P.ChristopoulosCharitos this happens because, as said in the ticket, Boost.Regex is compiled with normal ABI, while `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` changes it, thus the app using it crashes due to ABI mismatch.

Answer (score 6):

Yes: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

And many others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger.

Note also that most implementations of e.g. `std::vector` have a debug mode where they will do run-time bounds checking.

Answer (score 2):

There are some paid tools, which does *static analysis*:

[klockwork](http://www.klocwork.com/)

[coverity](http://www.coverity.com/)

IBM Rational **Purify** does dynamic analysis.

Answer (score 0):

create a  class on you arrays and create some controlling functions in that class 
with operators and ....
then use this class .