# How to check for std::vector out of range access

Tags: c++, std, outofrangeexception

[Found a doublicate here: [C++ - detect out-of-range access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497637/c-detect-out-of-range-access) ]

If I have a programm with "out of range vector access", like this:

```
  std::vector<int> A(2);
  ...
  A[10] = 3;
```

**Do I have a way to find this error for sure?**
I mean something like compile in debug mode and see whether some assertion stops the execution.

Up to now I have checked it by my own. But may be I don't have to write additional code?

---

P.S. I checked assertion of course. It doesn't called.

With this program:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> A(2);
  A[10] = 3;
  return 0;
}
```

compiled by

```
g++ 1.cpp -O0; ./a.out
```

So it looks like std doesn't have assertion in the code, I can't stop wonder why they don't make such a simple check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - detect out-of-range access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497637/c-detect-out-of-range-access)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function:

```
std::vector<int> A(2);

A.at(10) = 3;  //will throw std::out_of_range exception!
```

Since it may throw exception, you would like to catch it. So use `try{} catch{}` block!

Hope that helps.

Comment: www.google.com --> c++ out of range exception --> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/

Comment: @stellarossa: That is a bad site. Use this instead : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at

Comment: @Nawaz: i know. the point is, it's literally the first hit you get on google when you search for the problem, and it even gives you an example. i don't understand why people don't try that first. in fact, if you search for OP's exact question "How to check for std::vector out of range access" - guess what?

Comment: @stellarossa, oh, "How to check for std::vector out of range access" is almost exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @klm123: no worries, just try googling before posting here; whatever problem you have (especially if it's a beginner's problem), there's likely a solution on the net :)

Comment: @stellarossa, well, I found at() function. But I was not satisfied with it. I am not a guru of google...:)

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have a way to find this error for sure? I mean something like compile in debug mode and see whether some assertion stops the execution.

Valgrind easily catches these errors. Just run:

```
valgrind ./YOUR_EXECUTABLE
```

> I can't stop wonder why they don't make such a simple check.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239977/2030653).